# iMac 2012 RAM upgrade with mixed voltages

Tags: imac, memory

Variation of already asked question:

I now understand that I can add two matched 8 GB sticks of RAM into the two empty slots, even though the other two slots are filled with two 4 GB modules. But is there a problem having one pair 1.5v if the other pair are 1.3v?

It would appear to not be a problem, if as reported elsewhere, the iMac has 1.5v preinstalled and Crucial is recommending 1.35v sticks. Is that a faulty assumption?

Comment: With iMac 2012 you mean the model without an optical drive on the side? 21.5" or 27" model?

Comment: MacLemon: Late 2012 27"

Comment: You do know that Late 2012 27" are the ones that are new and thin, but I will refer it as 2013 model. Anyway, they are supposed to work anyway, but it's always better to use Apple default.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use anything but 1.5v RAM in the 27-inch iMac (Late 2012) as that's what my go-to Apple Memory site lists as compatible.

- [Ramjet recommends DDR3-1600, 1600Mhz, Non-ECC, Unbuffered, 1.5V, 204pin SO-DIMMs](http://ramjet.com/ItemDescription.asp?Item=IMIN32G)

I also can't believe I'm seeing 32 GB of memory for sale for just under $260 as that just seems too cheap to be true.

If you are looking elsewhere for RAM, I would encourage you to select non-stacked chips on the SO-DIMM as we don't know how warm these devices run and the last generation of 27-inch iMac put out significant heat and had a lot more aluminum to radiate that energy before a fan and convection were needed to assist in heat dissipation.

Comment: According to [this article over at OWC](http://blog.macsales.com/16144-27-imac-offers-easier-ram-upgrade) all iMac late 2012 models ship with 1.35 Low Voltage RAM...

Answer (score 0):

For the iMac 27" (Late 2012) model any RAM that fits the required specification can be used. The iMac (27-inch, Late 2012) has four SDRAM slots, each of which can accept a 4 GB, or 8 GB SO-DIMM.
RAM Spec from Apple's tech docs: `PC3-12800, (1600 MHz) DDR3, 204-pin, SO-DIMM`
4 * 8GB Modules can be obtained in Europe for under 200€. (YMMV)